# Can't bind ListView C#

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

Can't bind ObservableCollection with ListView. In ListView displays nothing. please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

I do not know what else to write, but the forum does not allow me to create a theme as many blocks of code

C# Code:

```
public ObservableCollection<MySQLCommand> _queryInf = new ObservableCollection<MySQLCommand>();
....
public ObservableCollection<MySQLCommand> queryInf
{
    get { return _queryInf; }
}
....
if (buffer[4] == 3)
{
     Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
     _queryInf.Add(new MySQLCommand() { Number = 0, Command = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 5, byteRec - 4), Memory = 0, Rows = 0, Time = 0 })));

}
...
public class MySQLCommand
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Command { get; set; }
    public int Time { get; set; }
    public int Memory { get; set; }
    public int Rows { get; set; }
}
```

XAML Code:

```
<ListView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="313" Margin="224,66,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="752" x:FieldModifier="public" Name="tProfiler" ItemsSource="{Binding queryInf}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridView.Columns>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="номер" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Number}"></GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="запрос" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Command}"></GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="время мс" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Time}"></GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="принято кб" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Memory}"></GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="строки" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Rows}"></GridViewColumn>
                </GridView.Columns>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: Have you checked Output window in VS?

Answer (score 0):

Your bindings syntax are just fine. Are you being able do bind anything at all from your view model? As @stukselbax mentioned, it's a good idea to star in the output bar.

Answer (score 0):

if you add `tProfiler.ItemsSource = _queryInf;` in the code, not in XAML, then the data will be displayed in ListView